# Phase shift in harmonic addition theorem

Tags: trigonometry

By the harmonic addition theorem,

$$ a \sin x + b \cos x = A \cos(x + \alpha) $$

Now,

$$ \alpha = \tan^{-1} \frac{b}{a}$$

My concern with this is that tan inverse has two solutions in the principle branch $[0,2\pi]$, so are these two equations solutions? What is the intuition behind the two different cosine waves denoting the same function?

Comment: Since $\cos(\theta+\pi)=-\cos\theta$, adding $\pi$ to $\alpha$ has the effect of changing the sign of $A$.

Comment: but you just showed it's negative!

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What does the word "it" in your sentence refer to? Anyway, say you have a pair $(A,\alpha)$ for which your equation is true. Then $\alpha+\pi$ is another angle whose tangent is $b/a$, but then the pair $(A,\alpha+\pi)$ won't work as a representation of the same function, rather $(-A,\alpha+\pi)$ will.

Comment: Ah I get it now, the sign of A also changes. I'll accept this if you post answer